# Dealing with a unique error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, unique

So I have got a database called Awards.

Users are able to 'award' a recipe but they can only do this once. The award database consists of recipe_id and user_id. I have made both of these columns unique so it wont allow you to award the recipe more than once. This works fine and if you attempt to award the recipe a second time I get this error:

```
columns user_id, recipe_id are not unique
```

Is there some code I can add into th create action to check for this error and then render a flash error message such as "already awarded recipe" instead of showing the error console?

this is my create method:

```
def create
  @award = current_user.awards.build(award_params)
  if @award.save
    flash[:success] = "Award Given!"
    redirect_to recipe_path(params[:recipe_id])
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a whole section of rails called validations that you're hitting on. The documentation is here: [link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). To get you basically set up, you could:

```
# award.rb
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :recipe_id
end

# awards_controller.rb
def create
  @award = current_user.awards.build(award_params)
  if @award.save
    flash[:success] = 'Award Given!'
    redirect_to recipe_path(params[:recipe_id])
  else
    flash[:error] = 'There was an error awarding this award!'
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed! Thanks very much. I realise i can't just use the unique method to validate!